# Is there any other rotated object detection datasets?

Tags: computer-vision, object-recognition

I have googled for a long time for rotated object detection datasets. Most of papers focused on rotated object detection using DOTA, HRSC2016 or coco text detection dataset. Some researcher also collect their own datasets but almost all of their theme is areal object detection. Is there any others dataset focus on rotated object detection?

Answer (score 1):

Multiscale Rotated Bounding Box-Based Deep Learning Method 
Here's [a link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6112046/) for a reference